# Cannot Open Messenger from iOS using Facebook 4.37.0

Tags: ios, facebook-messenger, fbsdksharekit

I am trying to open Facebook Messenger to send a message from my iOS app. I am currently running FaceBook SDK version 4.37.0. According to [iOS - Sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#message), this should be possible. It says

> People can also share content from your app to Facebook Messenger with Messenger Expression Platform or from Sharing's Message Dialog in iOS SDK.

If you click on the link for [Message Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#message), it provides you with the following example:

```
        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myFacebookURL];
        content.quote = @"My message";
        [FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

I have implemented this as well as the FBSDKSharingDelegate delegate methods of:

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NSLog(@"complete");
}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Sharer Error");
}

- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
}
```

The delegate methods never get called. What I would expect is that a Facebook Messenger dialog would open allowing me to select a friend to message. But nothing opens. And there are no errors being logged.

I do know that facebook is receiving something because I get the following:

```
FBSDKLog: param { 

"advertiser_id" = "xxxxxxxxx";
"advertiser_tracking_enabled" = 1;
"anon_id" = "xxxxxxxx";
"application_
tracking_enabled" = 1;
"custom_events" = "[{\"_eventName\":\"fb_mobile_content_view\",\"_logTime\":1541721304,\"fb_description\":\"MY FEATURE Sent\",\"_ui\":\"no_ui\"},{\"_ui\":\"no_ui\",\"_eventName\":\"fb_messenger_dialog_share_show\",\"_logTime\":1541721310,\"_implicitlyLogged\":\"1\",\"fb_dialog_share_content_type\":\"Status\"}]";
event = "CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS";
extinfo = "[\"i2\",\"com.myApp\",\"1\",\"8.3.6\",\"12.0.1\",\"iPhone10,6\",\"en_US\",\"CST\",\"AT&T\",375,812,\"3.00\",6,60,8,\"America\\/Chicago\"]";
"url_schemes" = "[\"myappID\",\"myscheme1\",\"myscheme2\",\"myscheme3\"]";
}
```

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
FBSDKMessageDialog.show(with: FBSDKShareLinkContent(), delegate: nil)
```

I have the same issue but experimentally I only pass FBSDKShareLinkContent() as a content param and messenger app start

You should also add fb-messenger-share-api key in Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes